# Aligning span, paragraph and anchor in css

Tags: html, css, css-position

I cannot figure out how to align these three elements. I have this scheme:

```
<div class="main_box">
    <span class="title">Title</span>
    <p>Text goes here</p>
    <a class="button" href="#">Button</a>
</div>
```

CSS is:

```
.title{
float:left;
display:inline-block;
}

p{
display: inline;
float: left;
width:100px;
}

.button{
display: inline;
float: right;
}
```

I put the width on `p`, because it's width is the width of container (and I don't want that).

With this, the button (anchor) is aligned with the paragraph, but I'd like to center it more, somewhere between title and paragraph.

What am I doing wrong? :\ Should I just use negative margin on the anchor?

EDIT: I wasn't clear enough, I need vertical alignment of these elements. I've figured out the problem. I can use negative margins.

Comment: If you have float on an element there is no point defining display inline-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can use here `display: inline-block;` no need to use `float`

```
.title, p, .button{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

p{
  width:100px; /* you can add width if you want */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're exactly going for but I think it's something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/kS4Dp/

You can change the width of the `<p>` to whatever is appropriate!

Answer (score 0):

The 'P' has a margin try:

```
p {     margin: 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZL2ef/

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS like below.

```
.title{
float:left;
}

p{
float:left;
width:100px;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
.button{
float:right;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/P4LY9/)